# Google Pub/Sub sending to only one subscription every ~5 messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I've made 3 clients connected to a subscription, and one publisher. In the image 2 of the subscriptions are on the terminal, and one subscription is not seen as it is hosted on a DigitalOcean Droplet. It seems every 5 messages, it switches which subscriber actually receives the message, which should not happen. I've also varied the speed and it's always about 5 messages.

Here is the code used on all clients for subscriptions:

```
sub.on("message", (msg) => {
  console.log(`Message:1 ${msg.data.toString("utf-8")}`)
  msg.ack()
})
```

And here is the code for publishing:

```
console.log("send")
topic.publish(Buffer.from("hey"), {
        channelId: "641273551806267403"
    })
```

[image]

Comment: My initial thought is that the design intention is one client per subscription... which seems very different than other platforms

Comment: My above thought seems to be the solution... I'll wait for another to chime in before I answer

Comment: The design depends. If you want multiple services responding to one queue of messages, use one subscription. If you want one message handled by more than one service (for example, one service logging the message in BigQuery and another processing the message) use multiple subscriptions. In the first case each service will handle a percentage of messages, the second case each service will handle all messages.

Comment: @JohnHanley that’s actually kind of cool, because you could do load balancing with the first case... Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Cloud Pub/Sub, a subscription is a logical entity that wants all messages published to the topic with which the subscription is associated. A subscriber is a client that receives messages on behalf of a subscription. When there are multiple subscribers receiving messages for a single subscription, then each subscriber receives a subset of the messages. This is the *load balancing* case, where one uses multiple subscribers to process messages at scale; if more messages need to be supported, one just turns up more subscribers to receive messages from the same subscription.

When a topic has multiple subscriptions, then every message has to be sent to a subscriber receiving messages on behalf of each subscription. This is the *fan out* use case.

Here is a graphic that tries to make it a little clearer. The left side is load balancing, the right side is fan out:

[image: load balancing and fan out]

Comment: In the Java Consumer client, we can control the number of consumer threads. So each thread is a separate 'Subscriber' in the above diagram ?   ref: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/1827

Comment: Thanks! Source: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#:~:text=The%20first%20subscription%20has%20two%20subscribers%2C%20meaning%20messages%20will%20be%20load%2Dbalanced%20across%20them%2C%20with%20each%20subscriber%20receiving%20a%20subset%20of%20the%20messages.