# Does Google Cloud (GCP) Pub/Sub supports feature similar to ConsumerGroups as in Kafka

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, google-cloud-pubsub

Trying to decide between Google Cloud (GCP) Pub/Sub vs Manager Kafka Service.

In latest update, Pub/Sub added support to replay messages which were processed before, is a welcome change.

One feature I am not able to find on their documentation is whether we can have  something similar to Kafka's Consumer Groups, i.e have group of Subscribers and each processing data from the same topic, and be able to re-process the data from beginning for some Subscriber(consumer group) while others are not affected by it.
eg:

Lets say you have a Topic as StockTicks

And you have two consumer groups

CG1: with two consumers 
CG2: With another two consumers

In Kafka I can read messages independently between these groups, but can I do the same thing with Pub/Sub.

And Kafka allows you to replay the messages from the beginning, can I do the same with Pub/Sub, I am ok if I cant replay the messages that were published before the CG was created, but can I replay the message that were submitted after a CG/Subscribers were created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub's equivalent of a Kafka's consumer groups is a subscription. Subscribers are the equivalent of a consumer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58750183/1121288) spells out the relationship between subscriptions and subscribers in a little more detail.

Your example in Cloud Pub/Sub terms would have a single topic, StockTicks, with two subscriptions (call them CG1 and CG2). You would bring up four subscribers, two that fetch messages for the subscription CG1 and two that fetch messages for the CG2 subscription. Acking and replay would be independent on CG1 and CG2, so if you were to seek back on CG1, it would not affect the delivery of messages to subscribers for CG2 at all.

Keep in mind with Cloud Pub/Sub that only messages published after a subscription is successfully created will be delivered to subscribers on that subscription. Therefore, if you create a new subscription, you won't get the all of the messages published since the beginning of time; you will only get messages published from that point on.

If you seek back on a subscription, you can only get up to 7 days of messages to replay (assuming the subscription was created at least 7 days ago) since that is the max retention time for messages in Cloud Pub/Sub.

Comment: Nope, pub/sub allows to replay messages, https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-overview.  And also ConsumerGroups work at higher level than simple subscriptions in Kafka, and especially would like to know if the GCP pub/sub supports that feature with replay  ing.

Comment: Pub/Sub allows to replay messages, but there is no guarantee that you will get messages published before the subscription was created. If you had another subscription from which you created a snapshot and then you seeked on your new subscription to that snapshot, you could get previous messages, but it would be the set of messages not acked by the original subscription from which the snapshot was taken, not the set of all messages necessarily. What is the "higher level than simple subscriptions" that ConsumerGroups does?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question with an example I am looking for. It will be fine where the messages will not be replayed that were submitted before a subscription was created. It appears a Subscription = ConsumerGroup in PubSub world? And can you have a specific Subscription replay messages while other Subscriptions getting not affected on the same topic?

Comment: When you say "CG1: with two subscriptions," what do you mean by "subscription" here? Do you mean a consumer, i.e., a task running that is receiving messages? Or is there some other notion of subscription to which you are referring?

Comment: It appears you can replay message in a specific subscription (consumer group) without affecting other subscriptions https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/replay-qs

Comment: It can send messages to subscribers that were added later as well, https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-py-mac

Comment: If the _subscriber_ was created later, yes. If the _subscription_ was created later, no. The distinction between subscriber and subscription here is very important.

Comment: I could create a subscriber with a subscription without expiration (default 30 days?) wouldn't that solve the problem?

Comment: That won't solve the the problem of getting messages created before the subscription was created. I'm trying to make sure that distinction is clear here. Also, even without expiration, you will still only get seven days of messages; the maximum retention time for messages is 7 days, even if the subscription's expiration is longer than that.

Comment: Posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882006/gcp-pub-sub-can-you-replay-old-messages-on-a-new-subscription-if-there-is-alrea